# Не изменяется язык интерфейса SQL Server Managment Studio 17.6

Tags: sql, sql-server

Вот такая ситуация ситуация.

```
Windows 2016 Server x64 Русский

SSMS - SQL Server Managment Studio 17.6
```

Установил SSMS Английскую версию, потом установил SSMS Русскую версию.
Русского языка в SSMS - нет. Удалил SSMS Английскую версию, потом удалил SSMS Русскую версию. Перегрузился. Еще раз установил SSMS Русскую версию.
В установке SSMS International Settings есть только два значения - English и Same as Microsoft Windows. В установке SSMS International Settings Русского языка нет. Установка SSMS International Settings в значение Same as Microsoft Windows результатов не дает. Язык все равно Английский.
Что делать в такой ситуации ?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте следующее:

1. Удалить все версии SSMS 2017
2. Удалить Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Shell (Isolated)
3. Установить русскую версию SSMS 2017 https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=870039&clcid=0x419